# How to tell Tramp to load a remote .bashrc before executing commands remotely?

Tags: tramp, ssh

**Problem:** I have an elisp plugin which is failing on a call to `start-file-process` when executed within a *remote* directory. The issue is that the command I am trying to call with `start-file-process` doesn't exist until my `/home/user/.bashrc` (within the remote machine) is executed. Here is the documentation for `start-file-process`:

> start-file-process is a compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> (start-file-process NAME BUFFER PROGRAM &rest PROGRAM-ARGS)
>
> :around advice: ‘start-file-process–with-editor-process-filter’
>
> Start a program in a subprocess. Return the process object for it.
>
> Similar to ‘start-process’, but may invoke a file handler based on ‘default-directory’. See Info node ‘(elisp)Magic File Names’.
>
> This handler ought to run PROGRAM, perhaps on the local host, perhaps on a remote host that corresponds to ‘default-directory’. In the latter case, the local part of ‘default-directory’, the one produced from it by ‘file-local-name’, becomes the working directory of the process on the remote host.
>
> PROGRAM and PROGRAM-ARGS might be file names. They are not objects of file handler invocation, so they need to be obtained by calling ‘file-local-name’, in case they are remote file names.
>
> File handlers might not support pty association, if PROGRAM is nil.
>
> [back]

**Question:** How do I tell `start-file-process` to source some bashrc file (e.g. `/home/user/.bashrc`) before it executes its command?

**Attempt;** Possibly relevant is `tramp-remote-process-environment` (I tried setting `BASH_ENV=/home/user/.bashrc`) but it didn't work).